# Angularjs $http request lost data when json key is begin with '$'

Tags: json, angularjs, http

I send a post request

payload is `

```
{
    'query': {
         "_id.domainName" : "receiver",
         "_id.name":"httpRequestCnt",
         "_id.timestamp":{
             "$gte":{
                 "$date": 0 
              },
              "$lt":{
                   "$date": 2000
              }
          }
      },
      "sort":{
           "_id.timestamp" : 1
      }
 }
```

when I check on my Chrome's debug log , I found '$gte' and '$lt' are lost.

Did you ever meet the same problem?

Comment: This looks very messy. First, the data should be quoted with double quotes, not randomly with sometime single, sometime double quotes. Not sure how you expect the "vtime" line to works, it's not quoted and JSON doesn't perform calculations. Then why $ appears to be escaped in some cases and not others. It shouldn't be escaped. So try again with correct quotes and see if it's any better.

Answer (score 0):

Angular < 1.3 stripped key names starting with `$`, as they were usually angular specific values (`$valid`, etc). After 1.3, it only strips `$$` prefixed keys.

Some solutions would be:

1. Use newer angular
2. Use different key names
3. Use native XHR / jquery (make sure to track your `$apply`s if you do it this way.